# Why is Object not a function?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im still learning Javascript and ReactNative, but following a set of tutorials for creating an app.

Why do i get an error stating that the Object passed to the component is not a function?  Is there any typo/syntax errors?

Button grid (main view):

```
    import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image } from "react-native";

import ButtonColumn from "../Button/ButtonColumn";

const ButtonGrid = () => {
  const handleCardPress = (item) => {
    console.log("test");
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <ButtonColumn item="Text1" handleCardPress={handleCardPress} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ButtonGrid;
```

Component view:

```
    import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

import styles from "./buttonColumn.style";

const ButtonColumn = (item, handleCardPress) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnStyle} onPress={handleCardPress(item)}>
        <Text style={{}}>Test1</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnStyle}>
        <Text style={{}}>Test2</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnStyle}>
        <Text style={{}}>Test3</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ButtonColumn;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not extracting the props correctly in this line:

```
const ButtonColumn = (item, handleCardPress) => {
```

The props is passed in as an object, so `item` currently is an object with the structure `{ item, handleCardPress }`, and `handleCardPress` is just an empty object `{}`.

To fix, you can destructure the props correctly by changing that line to this:

```
const ButtonColumn = ({ item, handleCardPress }) => {
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved it, having abit hard time wrapping my head around curly brackets uses.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it! Can you upvote and accept the answer if it solved the issue? :)
Props will always be passed to a component as a single object, so you can either destructure it directly in the component declaration, or assign it to a variable (conventionally called `props`) and access the properties as `props.item` / `props.otherProp`. It's called [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), in case you want to read more about it :)

Comment: Thank you very much :) Had to wait for the timer to run down before marking as answered but this helps alot :)